# how to disable a function for 20 seconds after the page is loaded

Tags: javascript

I want to disable javascript functions for 20 sec after the page is loaded...

Here start PHP code to disable for 20 sec my code

```
 $LeAdClickonline = get_option('video-LeAdClick-online');
    if ($LeAdClickonline === 'on') {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'video_LeAdClick_localized', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) .  '/js/leadclick.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
  }
```

so all what i need is to disable functions for this code for 20sec when page is loaded Thanks

Comment: [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Pleas can you tell me exactly how?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan gives you the documentation, read and try yourself, if you get some error post it

Comment: I want to know how I can do it in my case? i have edit my question again , and i have add my code so like this I hope my question is clearer, Thanks again.

Comment: @Stronzi Try it first! [here is setTimeout() english version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) :)

Comment: I guess you should mention your goal here, I am pretty sure there may be other ways to achieve it.. because `disable javascript` makes no sense.

Comment: if i try that by my self  i need more then 1 year, but thanks for your help @aloisdg

Answer (score 1):

Use a comibination of [$(document).ready()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Here is an example

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    //start timeout to wait for 20 second (20000 milliseconds) before executing delayed_function()
    setTimeout (delayed_function, 20000)
});

//this function will get executed after 20 seconds
function delayed_function () {
    alert ('20 seconds had passed after the document was ready');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, my question is how to set that part of the code that I want to turn off the function for 20 sec, i have edit my question so if you have time take a look, Thanks again for your help

Comment: He asked for a solution with JavaScript, not using Jquery or any other library.

Comment: @Sarin for me it does not matter what the code for me really matters how to fix this, Thanks for your help

Comment: @Sarin it is tagged wit `jquery`... so i guess its ok.

Comment: @Stronzi can you be more specific about `I want to turn off the function for 20 sec`? because that is what `setTimeout()` does.

Comment: I'm sorry
i want to sy disable the function, exactly i want to disaple the function which comes from this link `/js/leadclick.js` My English is not so good so I have to use Google, Thanks for your help @wayneOS

Comment: Ah ok i think i get it. you have ja .js file included over a `<script>` tag and want to delay the execution of the main-function of this file, right? mhh either you edit the file with a setTimeout() or you add the script-tag after 20-seconds.

Comment: Thanks again @wayneOS yes is that what i try to do but i have problem beucose that code what i have is php, and i don't know how to add that, i try to fix, im not that good for script, just i like to do this, thanks again

Comment: @Stronzi wait, what? PHP-code? i thought it was a javascript-file? could you maybe update your question with detailed information what you actually want to do? show the php-code and the javascript and where exactly you want your delay.

Comment: Yes my code was PHP, :/ Sorry for that but i edit my question now

Comment: @Stronzi well then it is not possible to delay that after your page has loaded. php is server-side and already finished before it gets loaded in your browswer.

Comment: so is not posible to disable this `js/leadclick.js` so the content is coming from this link, that is what i want to disable, but thanks for your help, my question was wrong so what i do do i delte this question?

Comment: Yes you can delay `js/leadclick.js` because it is a javascript file. maybe let this question open (because people will loose theire reputation if you delete it) and just open a new one. but this time try to show what you want to accomplish. then i will happy to help you ;)

Comment: pleas if you have time take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586091/jquery-hide-this-class-for-20-seconds-after-the-page-is-loaded my new question Thanks

Comment: I guess you already got good answers on your new question. Or is it still not what you want? Anyway, do you mind accepting my answer here?

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this - Since you have asked for a JavaScript solution.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // Handler when the DOM is fully loaded
  setTimeout(function(){
    //your code to be delayed by 20 sec
    alert("Hello"); // for testing
   }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, my question is how to set that part of the code that I want to turn off the function for 20 sec, i have edit my question so if you have time take a look, Thanks again for your help

Comment: Thanks for your help @ElkhanMamedov

Comment: @Stronzi please accept the answer, if it solved your problem.

Comment: your code is working, but i have some problem to add my code in that beaucose my code is php, after i fix it i do that, thanks for your help @Sarin

Comment: maybe like this is working but somthing is minding here, and my website  if i add this is not working. thanks for your help @ElkhanMamedov

Comment: pleas if you have time take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586091/jquery-hide-this-class-for-20-seconds-after-the-page-is-loaded my new question Thanks