# Hide This Class after the page is loaded and show after for 20 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, this is working, but i want to hidden fast so 1 sec is to mouch, i want to hide this less then 1 sec and show after 20 seconds ?

```
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".video-LeAdClick-front").show(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".video-LeAdClick-front").hide()
      }, 1000)
    })
  }, 20000)
})
```

Comment: Why not start with it hidden and then after 20 seconds, show it?

Comment: so timeout set to 20 seconds, seems easy enough....

Comment: that is what i want to do to start with hidden and then after 20 seconds @gforce301 Thanks

Comment: So hide it with CSS, not Javascript, and then execute a show function (or remove a class name that causes it to be hidden) after 20 seconds.

Comment: You're not explaining it very well, and between your own code and the two answers below (correct as per your previous version of the question), you've already got enough code to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly note that you don't need multiple document.ready event handlers in a single page. You can combine them.

Secondly, I'm assuming, given that you're calling `hide()` on the element currently, that the element is visible on load of the page and you want to hide it 20 seconds *after* the page has loaded, not hide it *for* 20 seconds then display it.

To achieve that you can use a `setTimeout()` call, like this:

```
$(function() {
  var $video = $(".video-LeAdClick-front").attr('target', '_blank');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $video.hide(1000);
  }, 20000);
});
```

If the inverse is true (ie. the element should start hidden then be displayed after 20 seconds) then just flip the `hide()` to `show()`:

```css
.video-LeAdClick-front { display: none; }
```

```
$(function() {
  var $video = $(".video-LeAdClick-front").attr('target', '_blank');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $video.show(1000);
  }, 20000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help i have try this but is not working, so i want to hidden and show after 20sec, thanks for your help

Comment: no your code is correct but maybe my question was wrong, thanks for your help i have edit my question now, thanks again

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, why not initiate with `display: none`:

```
.video-LeAdClick-front { display: none }
```

and then in your `ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".video-LeAdClick-front").show().click(function() {
            $(this).hide(1000);
        });
    }, 20000);
});
```

Alternatively, using `visibility`:

```
.video-LeAdClick-front { visibility: hidden }
```

and then in your `ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".video-LeAdClick-front").css({"visibility" : "visible"}).click(function() {
            $(this).hide(1000);
        });
    }, 20000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help i have try this but is not working, so i want to hidden and show after 20sec, thanks for your help

Comment: no your code is correct but maybe my question was wrong, thanks for your help i have edit my question now, thanks again

Comment: OK - I'll go back and check your question after you edit

Comment: i have edit my question,  @David Thanks for your help

Comment: I took a look at your edit - I think my answer still works for you. There is no need to use Javascript or jQuery to hide something if "visibility: hidden" or "display: none" is your initial state. Use CSS for this - then after your x second delay, show it using Javascript or jQuery. Also added code to handle using visibility if this is your intent.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: sorry i have try again your code but is not working, that what i have get from internet that is working, so all what i need is to hiden more fast, but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**The solution after 2 days**

```
$(function(){
$(".video-LeAdClick-front").hide();
})
```

Thanks for your help.